# Select the oldest and the youngest employees in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to select the oldest and the youngest employees in the workplace. The oldest and the youngest refer to their working experience.
I referred to previous questions with SQL server and modified my code as below, but I had the error:

> invalid identifier.

I wonder would there be any suggestions for me to change my code?

```
 SELECT d.Dtable_name,
        RANK() OVER(ORDER BY SUM(ROUND((SYSDATE - e.hire_date) / 365.24,0)) DESC) AS yrsexperience
   FROM Dtable_department d
   LEFT JOIN Etable_employee e
     ON d.department_id=e.department_id
WHERE yrsexperience =(SELECT MAX(d.department_name) KEEP(DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY SUM(ROUND((SYSDATE - e.hire_date) / 365.24,0)) DESC) AS yrsexperience) AS Oldest)FROM Etable_employee e)

OR yrsexperience =(SELECT
       MIN(d.department_name) KEEP(DENSE_RANK LAST  ORDER BY SUM(ROUND((SYSDATE - e.hire_date) / 365.24,0)) DESC) AS yrsexperience) AS Youngest
  FROM Etable_employee e)
```

### Update

I edited the code after referring to the answer below, but it threw me the error:

> FROM is not found where expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `FIRST` and `LAST` aggregate functions.

```
SELECT MAX(name) KEEP(DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY yrs_experience ) AS Youngest,
       MAX(name) KEEP(DENSE_RANK LAST  ORDER BY yrs_experience ) AS Oldest
  FROM etable_employee;
```

Comment: Thank you! But what if I would like to add department_name from Dtable_department? This result only showed the oldest and the youngest date.

Comment: @Chen , please add it in select and group by with proper aliases. It should work. I may give you the query but I wish you would try.

Comment: thanks!! I did try and edited my original post. Would you mind letting me know where I had missed? It threw me error as if I lost a "From" syntax.

Comment: @chen : Preferably ask another question.. This answers original question of finding oldest nd newest.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `YRSEXPERIENCE` is a field on `ETABLE_EMPLOYEE`. Given that, I would expect that

```
SELECT *
  FROM ETABLE_EMPLOYEE
  WHERE YRS_EXPERIENCE IN (SELECT MIN(YRS_EXPERIENCE) FROM ETABLE_EMPLOYEE
                           UNION ALL
                           SELECT MAX(YRS_EXPERIENCE) FROM ETABLE_EMPLOYEE)
```

would give you what you're looking for.

### EDIT

Based on further information:

```
SELECT SYSDATE - e.HIRE_DATE AS YRS_EXPERIENCE
  FROM ETABLE_EMPLOYEE e
  WHERE SYSDATE - e.HIRE_DATE IN (SELECT MIN(SYSDATE - HIRE_DATE) FROM ETABLE_EMPLOYEE
                                  UNION ALL
                                  SELECT MAX(SYSDATE - HIRE_DATE) FROM ETABLE_EMPLOYEE)
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=76cfd35796602876178b8a0056fd6322)

Comment: Thank you very much! But YRSEXPERIENCE is I tried to create by deducting SYSDATE and hire-date, which is a field in Etable_employee. So your code still generated "YRSEXPERIENCE" is invalid identifier....